# How we create a custom photo album in UIActivityViewController ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiactivityviewcontroller

I have groups of photos and I want to create a custom album and post that album to facebook.

Answer (score 0):

To create a custom photo album in iOS you need to deal with the `AVAssets library`.

There is a really nice and [handy component on GitHub](https://github.com/Kjuly/ALAssetsLibrary-CustomPhotoAlbum) to save pictures and videos to a predefined album of your choice.